# How to derive a pseudo random number, given a parent/seed number - which fits all criteria the parent number has

Tags: math, random, lua, numbers, random-seed

I need some help with maths. I am generating a derived seed value from a parent seed value.

I need to derive a number y given a number x which follows the following rules.

1. `x = math.random(1000, 9999)`
2. for a given x, y is constant. ie. `y = f(x)`
3. y doesnt necessarily follows x. ie y doesnt needs to grow when x grows and y doesnt needs to reduce when x reduces.
   eg. if x = 1234 and in the next iteration `x = 3456` then y also doesnt needs to grow. in fact y would better be a pseudo random number.
4. y also is in the range (1000, 9999)

Early on i went for the following function:

```
y = tonumber(string.reverse(x))
```

ie. if `x = 1234` then `y = 4321`

However there is a direct correlation between the two numbers and my terrain is looking way too symmetric as a result.

Comment: So, basically you want a hash function?

Comment: Though, in the end, you'll always end up with a direct correlation as for any given `x`, you get a fixed value for `y`.

Comment: Not sure if it is a hash function. But yeah, I want the output y to have very little coorelation with x as possible.

Comment: One function i was thing of was would use an infinite float like pi.

for x = 1000, take 1st 4 decimal places of pi.
for x= 1001 take the next 4 and so on.
if any output is less than 100, then just skip 1 character and check.

Since pi is a constant number, a value of x will always gives a specific value of y.

however, this feels very daunting in practice and i am not sure how can i implement something like this efficiently. I am pretty inexperienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the generated value of `x` back into the `math.randomseed` function. The RNG will always generate the same value of `y` for same value of `x` passed to seed.

So, something like:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local r = math.random
local x = r(1000, 9999)
math.randomseed(x)
local y = r(1000, 9999)
```

to test whether it works, as an example, you could use `5668` as seed (or `x`), and for `y` you'll always get back **[3612](https://eval.in/632494)**. You can even test it on https://lua.org/demo.html

Comment: I really like this. So simple and solves my problem perfectly.